# Using differentials in integration by substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I am confused why we can introduce differentials into an integral when performing an integration by substitution.

Consider the integral
$$\int \frac{1}{ x \sqrt{1-x} } dx.$$
We can perform the substitutions $$x=\sin^2u,$$ $$dx=2\sin u \cos{u} du  ,$$ on the integral to give $$\int \frac{1}{ \sin^2u \sqrt{1-\sin^2u} } 2\sin u \cos u du .$$

**Why can you treat $dx$ as a differential?**

From my understanding the integration sign $\int dx$ works as as if it is an **operator**, just like how $\frac {d}{dx}$ works as an **operator** and not as a fraction. Which means $\int$ and $dx$ should not be interpreted separately.

But at the same time treating $dx$ as a differential always work out fine so there must be some validness in treating it as an differential.

Comment: $1-x>0\implies x<1$ But $x$ can be $<-1$ right? Better use $\sqrt{1-x}=y$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Hi, I was using a suggested substitution given in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2841480/how-to-integrate-x-sqrt1-x-1. Anyway, the exact substitution isn't really the problem I am trying to understand. But thanks!

Comment: The $\mathrm d x$ term in an integral should remind you of the $\Delta x$ in Riemann sums, which is really an increase of  the integration variable and can be approximated by the differential.

Comment: This is just a handy recipe. (Of course there is a proof behind it, using the chain rule.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the $\frac {d}{dx}$ is just a notation of the differential

$$\frac {d}{dx} f(x)  = \lim_{\delta x\to0}{\frac {f(x+\delta x)-f(x)}{\delta x}}   $$
or we can say that :

$$\frac {d}{dx} f(x)  = \lim_{\delta x\to0} {\frac {\delta f(x)}{\delta x}}   $$

with $$ df(x) =\lim_{\delta x\to0} f(x+\delta x)-f(x)= \lim_{\delta x\to0} \delta f(x)$$ 
so the notation $\frac {d}{dx}$ is actually a fraction and not just a notation of an Operator.

by writing this:
$$ g(x)=\frac {d f(x)}{dx}     $$

if you know the function $g(x)$ and you looking for $f(x)$ we need firstly to know this $d f(x)$

we must multiply both side with  $dx$ and get that :
         $$d f(x)   = g(x) \space dx $$

so Now the time of the Inverse Operator of the " $d $ " 
the sum of Riemann is the same idea
 $$\sum d f(x)   = \sum g(x) \space dx = f(x)  $$
it's not correct exactly because the sum must be continued, then we can renotated the continued sum as an Integral  $\int$ :

$$\int d f(x)   = \int g(x) \space dx = f(x)  $$

so it's not just a symbole